# How a can split file line with many spaces in C# asp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, file, split

I need your help. I have a txt file with many lines of information.

The headers of the file are

Date                ReferenceNumber             Description                                                                                                                           
13/06/2013 00000081985                  TRF DESDE OTRO BCO          00000000000000972353 
           0105

Mount                                Money                                                                                                                                            +50.000,00                                           344.514,74

Between Description and Mount are many spaces

Here's a image of the file [image]

I need split this line to get all the attributes by separate.

I need, Date = 13/06/2013, ReferenceNumber = 00000081985, ....

I'm trying to use split C# function to separate by (' ') but i only can get the 2 first attributes =(

I hope you can help me! Thanks a lot.

Comment: The problem is, that space is at the same time a separator, and part of the content. How do you know, which role particular space plays in your input?

Comment: I'd suggest you ask the data supplier how they generate that data as it doesn't look like it's space delimited. Is it tab delimited?

Comment: The fields look fixed length to me.

Comment: i would to like show a screenshot to you @MarcinJuraszek

Comment: Probably it for tabs delimitation @NeilThompson

Comment: For tab separated, shouldn't we use '\t' in the split function ?

Comment: I'm betting it's a fixed length file - i.e., each column has a specified length.  The numeric values are probably right-justified.

Comment: If you open this file with a text editor (notepad) and set a fixed width font (Lucida Console, Courier) do you see your data exactly aligned in column aligned? If yes then you have a fixed length data and all you need to know is the size of each column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to look to see what the length of each field is because it does look like fixed length data. If so use the [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method, using the starting position and the max length of each field as inputs.

Comment: And then you can use `Trim()` to get rid of the extra spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you're trying to deal with a fixed length file, which is essentially a file with data that is split based on its physical location in the file (each piece of data is expected to occupy a specific number of characters). Seems to be one of those lesser known functions, but check out [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx). It's a .NET class specifically made for this sort of thing.

Specifically, check out the property `TextFieldType`, which can be set to `FixedWidth` and given a width of each of those fields. Should do exactly what you want.

Comment: You need to mention that he needs to include the VisualBasic Namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like this:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("path to text file");
string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
s = s.Replace(' ', '!'); //change the space sign with other sign
List<string> strList = s.Split('!').ToList();
strList.RemoveAll(t => t == "");
```

I know the solution isn't best but I hope it will help you.

Comment: Are you serious? OK, let's start with: What if the original string contains exclamation marks? But it's pretty creative way of thinking, indeed. Perhaps you can choose a series of chars that eliminate the chance of having it in the original string. Something like `"{!=!}"`.

Comment: Yes, I know that I thought about a series of chars. It's only an example how it can be done.

Comment: Again, I really like your creative thinking. However, the biggest struggle is that the spaces in the Description field are not separators, so you will have to join the parts back together. Your code will actually achieve the same results as mine if you follow the same logic at the end to collect the fields from `strList`. So after your last line, you take the first two fields `strList[0]` and `strList[1]`, then you take the last two fields `strList[strList.Count - 1]` and `strList[strList.Count - 2]`, then finally join all the parts left together with spaces.

Comment: Guess you're right, collecting fields can be easily done here. After all it doesn't matter how you'll do it, the outcome is what matters.

Comment: Well, it does actually matter in some cases how you do it, for instance if the performance is critical. I guess my way is slightly faster, but not sure. If performance is not an issue, you way has a bit less code and simpler to read.

Comment: And one last thing, both our ways assume that the OP does not mind removing the extra spaces from the description field (I'm still waiting for his answer to this), but if this is not correct and he does care, then perhaps he won't be able to use your way. My way gives us more control and I will be able to modify it to accommodate that requirement if needed.